# How to install maven 2.2.1 in redhat?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to install maven 2.2.1 in redhat6
I have downloaded maven file `openlogic-maven-2.2.1-all-bin-1.zip` extracted in folder called maven. after extraction I get a folder called `maven-2.2.1` .This is the path where I have extracted maven `/home/qaserver/app/maven`.

After that I set home path for maven in `.bash_profile`.
this is the content of `.bash_profile`

```html
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

JAVA_HOME=/home/qaserver/app/java/jdk1.6.0_45
export JAVA_HOME

M2_HOME=/home/qaserver/app/maven/maven-2.2.1
export M2_HOME

PATH=$M2/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

after setting the home path when I run `mvn -version` I get `bash: mvn: command not found`

I have set install java same way, but my maven is not working where as when I type java -version. I get this

`java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)`

1. Is there any thing wrong in `.bash_profile` ?
2. one more problem I am facing that I need to run .bash_profile every
   time when ever I restsrt my system or open any new terminal to run
   java -version

I don't want to install maven using command.because I need to configure java and maven now and then maximum time. Thats why I want to keep the installation process simple, so that I can change it easily

Comment: Don't install [Maven 2 anymore](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple.
Please modify it as

```
PATH=$M2_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The change is to use M2_HOME rather than M2.

This would do the trick. Please let know if it works.

Comment: What terminal are You using?

Comment: try adding exec `source ~/.bash_profile` to the .profile. Thus it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: in `etc` folder `profile` and `profile~` I need to add in `source ~/.bash_profile` in   `profile` right?

Comment: Sorry but I dont have any file called profile in home. I also checked in home there is no usr also. usr is there in file system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89876/discussion-between-melvins-and-varun).

Answer (score 1):

On the following:

```
PATH=$M2/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Please use `$M2_HOME` instead of `$M2`. `$M2` will just result to an empty string, hence your maven binary, `mvn` can't be found.